# how to remove datamodel from core data and add a new one?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am working on a iphone application project. we have released one application with a coredata model, now in our new release we like to remove the old one and add a new one. (we are not storing any user values on existing core data model).  we forgot to remove the xcdatamodel from our application folder, but we removed all code relate to core data. Now we have to remove xcdatamodelfile and its related h and m class.

in our new project  bundle can we create a new core data model and submit that application? i like to  know this new xcdatamodel will create any problem for the users while updating our new release?

thanks!
Ram

Answer (score 0):

> in our new project bundle can we
>   create a new core data model and
>   submit that application?

Never forget to make a complete rebuild after changing the datamodel, as the build process sometimes does not correctly recognize datamodel changes

> i like to
>   know this new xcdatamodel will create
>   any problem for the users while
>   updating our new release?updating our new release?

As you do not need any old data/migration create the persistent store in a new location and the old model/old data file will not be a problem at all. (given the model has been properly replaced by the new one)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a bit tricky but this always works for me. This is for a **clean** installation of a new compatible .sqlite file, **not a migration**!

launch simulator, delete the app and the data (the popup after you delete the app).

quit simulator

open X-Code, after making any edits to your data model

if needed update the datamodel version:

1. `Editor > Add Model Version...`
2. set your prefs in the dialog that appears (counting up is preferable)
3. click on the {appname}.xcdatamodeld then in the far right pane
4. click the left icon of the 3 icons on top of the far right column
5. under `Versioned Core Data Model` select the one you just created

delete the `{appname}.sqlite` file (or back it up, remove it from project folder, and delete reference)

clean the app (`Product > Clean`)

Run the app in a simulator (for this tutorial I will assume 4.2)

While the simulator is running, in a Finder window, navigate to: 
`{home} > Library > Application Support > iPhone Simulator > 4.2 > Applications > {random identifier} > Documents > {appname}.sqlite`

**Copy** this file to another location

Stop running your app in X-Code

Drag and drop the {appname}.sqlite file into the files list  in X-Code.

In the dialog that pops up, make sure the `copy to folder` checkbox, is checked.

`Product > Clean`

Then run the app in the simulator again

Now you should have a working sqlite file!

Cheers,
Robert